# Python program is executing first if condition only

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am trying to create a basic program in python, where I perform calculations based on sentences. For that I have created if/else conditions but after running the program it is taking the first condition every time, do you have any idea why it is happening?

```
import re
query = 'plus 5 and 3'

def multiply(query):
    query = '*'.join(re.findall('\d+',query))
    print(f'{eval(query)}')
    return f'Answer is {eval(query)}'

def addition(query):
    query = '+'.join(re.findall('\d+',query))
    print(f'{eval(query)}')
    return f'Answer is {eval(query)}'

def subtract(query):
    query = '-'.join(re.findall('\d+',query))
    print(f'{eval(query)}')
    return f'Answer is {eval(query)}'

def divide(query):
    query = '/'.join(re.findall('\d+',query))
    print(f'{eval(query)}')
    return f'Answer is {eval(query)}'  
    
    
    

if 'multiplication' or 'multiply' in query:
    print(multiply(query))

elif 'addition' or 'add' or 'plus' in query:
    print(addition(query))

elif 'subtraction' or 'subtract' or 'minus' in query:
    print(subtract(query))

elif 'division' or 'divide' in query:
    print(divide(query))
```

Comment: give reason for down voting my question

Comment: Besides the proposed answers, and since you are already using regex, you could do `if re.match('multiplication|multiply', query):`. This can make your code more concise if you have many alternative words.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot say `if 'multiplication' or 'multiply' in query`. If you want to check if one of those two words is in query, then you must do it like this:
`if 'multiplication' in query or 'multiply' in query`. You will need to change this for all 4 if statements.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking for `if 'multiplication' or if 'multiply' in query`.
what you want to check is `if 'multiplication' in query or if 'multiply' in query`

the correct code would be:

```
import re
query = 'plus 5 and 3'

def multiply(query):
    query = '*'.join(re.findall('\d+',query))
    print(f'{eval(query)}')
    return f'Answer is {eval(query)}'

def addition(query):
    query = '+'.join(re.findall('\d+',query))
    print(f'{eval(query)}')
    return f'Answer is {eval(query)}'

def subtract(query):
    query = '-'.join(re.findall('\d+',query))
    print(f'{eval(query)}')
    return f'Answer is {eval(query)}'

def divide(query):
    query = '/'.join(re.findall('\d+',query))
    print(f'{eval(query)}')
    return f'Answer is {eval(query)}'  
    
    
    

if 'multiplication' in query or 'multiply' in query:
    print(multiply(query))

elif 'addition' in query or 'add' in query or 'plus' in query:
    print(addition(query))

elif 'subtraction' in query or 'subtract' in query or 'minus' in query:
    print(subtract(query))

elif 'division' in query or 'divide' in query:
    print(divide(query))
```